# Drop down selected index changed on page load

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down box that populates textbox values based on its value. It fires when it is changed but on pageload it doesnt fire. How do I get it to fire on page load?

```
   protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
   TextBox3.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        TextBox12.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        TextBox21.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

     //etc
```

Comment: Have you set `AutoPostback=true`? Otherwise the dropdwown will not postback immediately when the user selects something.

Comment: autopost back is set to true, but textboxes are not populating unless I fire the drop down manually by selecting a different value.

Comment: Yes, because an event-handler is always triggered by a user-action. It should not be called programmatically. But you could refactor the code and create a method that populates your TextBoxes. Then you can call this method from page_load **and** from the event-handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim Schmelter's comment is right on the money.

```
// Wire up to the page load event
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   updateTextBoxes();
}

// Wire up to the select index-changed event
protected void DropDownList1_SelectIndexChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    updateTextBoxes();
}


// your workhorse method
protected void updateTextBoxes()
{
   TextBox3.Text  = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
   TextBox12.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
   TextBox21.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

   // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't be called automatically at page load, you have to call it "manually":

```
 void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

     // ....

     DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(DropDownList1, e);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedIndexChanged` fires in response to a user-driven change. Move the assignment logic to another method and call it manually from `Page_Load` and also from your event handler.